# Why this property isn't visible? Says attachable property can't be found

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, behavior

I'm creating Behavior with attached properties. Behavior should attach to Grid:

```
public class InteractionsBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Container", typeof(Grid), typeof(Grid), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InteractionsProviderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InteractionsProvider", typeof(IInteractionsProvider), typeof(Grid), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged));

    public Grid Container
    {
        get { return GetValue(ContainerProperty) as Grid; }
        set { this.SetValue(ContainerProperty, value); }
    }

    public IInteractionsProvider InteractionsProvider
    {
        get { return GetValue(InteractionsProviderProperty) as IInteractionsProvider; }
        set { this.SetValue(InteractionsProviderProperty, value); }
    }
```

Now when I'm writing XAML like this I get error:

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
          Behaviors:InteractionsBehavior.InteractionsProvider="{Binding InteractionsProvider}">
```

> Error 4   The property 'InteractionsProvider' does not exist on the type
> 'Grid' in the XML namespace
> 'clr-namespace:Infrastructure.Behaviors;assembly=Infrastructure.SL'.  C:\MainPage.xaml    11  11  Controls.SL.Test
>
> Error 1   The attachable property 'InteractionsProvider' was not found
> in type
> 'InteractionsBehavior'.   C:\MainPage.xaml    11  11  Controls.SL.Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified that it only should be available to be attached ("owned") by an `InteractionsBehavior`.  If you want to be able to assign this to a grid, change the RegisterAttached line to:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InteractionsProviderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InteractionsProvider", typeof(IInteractionsProvider), typeof(Grid), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnInteractionsProviderPropertyChanged));
```

(Or use some base class in `Grid`'s class hierarchy...)

Comment: I just edited my post - it's the same issue - I get same error. I wonder if something wrong with class itself? What Behavior<Grid> means?

Comment: @katit THat's an expression behavior - if you're using that, you probably don't want an attached property.  You'd typically use either a Behavior<T> OR an Attached Property.  You also need to fix your specification of the get/set accessor if you want to use an attached property - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

Comment: I wasn't aware of different behavior types. Right now it seems that expression behavior will be more suitable for me since it seems to have "state". You answered my question, I will appreciate if you have pointer to good tutorial on how to write expression behavior

Comment: @katit Try: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/08/15/custom-behaviors-in-silverlight-3-and-blend-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the declaration of your attached property.  Attached properties have 4 parts: the name, the type, the owner type, and the property metadata.  You're specifying that the InteractionsProvider property is owned (and thus supplied) by the type Grid.  That's not actually the case.  Change the owner type (third parameter) to `typeof(InteractionsBehavior)` (the class in which you've declared the attached property), switch to static get/set methods instead of a property (because you're using an attached property, not a dependency property), and it should all work as you expect.

Comment: Mike, I marked Reed's answer. Actually, it started to work when I added SetInteractionsProvider and GetInteractionsProvider as per naming convention. However, "static" nature of this code doesn't seem to be working for me, I will need to explore into Expression behaviors

Comment: Try this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2009/03/23/an-introduction-to-behaviors-triggers-and-actions.aspx